# Specifying DAG queue via Airflow's UI TriggerDag parameters

Tags: celery, airflow

thanks for reading this question.

I accomplished to set up an Airflow cluster following the official instructions [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) and I managed to add workers hosted at remote machines. It seems that everything works fine (connections to Redis and Postgre are working and DAG tasks are distributed and executed properly across the different workers).

Also, I can execute DAGs at a specific worker by subscribing each worker to an exclusive queue and hardcoding the `queue` parameter of each operator in the DAG.

**My problem is** I would like to be able to parametrize said execution queue via Airflow CLI, with the help of the Trigger DAG button. I tried using Jinja Templates and XComs, but these options didn't help me with my problem since Jinja Templates don't seem to work on the parameters of Operators and XCom needs the `ti` parameter or Jinja Templates.

I know some people have written plugins in order to simplify this task, but since all the information I found was prior to Airflow 2.x I wanted to know if there was already a solution for this problem.

Thank you so much in advance

Edit: I would like to do this: [Triggering DAG via UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luXN9.png).

However,

```py
        task_test = BashOperator(
        task_id='test2',
        queue='{{ dag_run.conf['queue'] }}',
        bash_command="echo hi",
        )
```

Does not work, since the job gets queued at `{{ dag_run.conf['queue'] }}` instead of `queue1`

I also tried the following approach, and it doesnt work either, as all
jobs get scheduled on `default` queue:

```py
    with DAG(
        'queue_execution_test',
        default_args=default_args,
        description='Test specific execution.',
        schedule_interval=None, # Para que solo se ejecute on demand
        start_date=days_ago(2),
    ) as dag:

    run_on_queue = 'default' #'{{ dag_run.conf["queue"] if dag_run else "default" }}'

    def parse_queue_parameter(ti, **kwargs): # Task instance for XCom and kwargs for dagrun parameters
        try:
            ti.xcom_push(key='custom_queue', value= kwargs['dag_run'].conf['queue'] )
        except:
            print("No queue defined")

    initial_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='test1',
        queue=run_on_queue,
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=parse_queue_parameter,
    )


    task_test = BashOperator(
        task_id='test2',
        queue=run_on_queue,
        bash_command="echo hi",
    )

    initial_task.set_downstream(task_test)
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what is the question. Can you share some code to better describe where exactly is the issue?

Comment: @Elad Thank you for your quick answer, I added more information on the question. I hope it is more clear now!

Comment: I guess since `queue` param from `BaseOperator` is not a templated field, the alternative is to create your own operator, with a templated field that allows you to fetch the parameter you want to pass from the UI. I'm not sure if there is a more scalable solution.

Comment: @NicoE I see. So I guess that I have to create a custom operator for every operator that I want to use with this "feature", or use another templated field that I do not intend to use at that job to parse the parameter. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @Mathias yes, that's what I understand. Let's see if anyone else knows a better way to solve this (I think it's interesting).